# Would a duplicate DC on same subnet be bad, if ALL auth is only internal to the server?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

Here's a weird scenario I'm looking for some guidance on.

I have a VM that is a purpose-built "self-contained" demo environment.  It has an application stack installed, as well as Active Directory, where it is the only Domain Controller and has all roles.

The AD instance is ONLY used for authentication of the users that run the applications that are installed on this same server.  Again, the intention is to have a completely self-contained environment.

Now, I've gotten a request to clone this VM and put two copies on the same subnet.  Everything I know about AD is making me reject this request, and I'm going to put it behind a pfsense VM, on another subnet.

BUT - the question I have is: would there actually be any real problems if I put 2 exact copies of this particular domain controller on the same subnet?  (Obviously I would change the IP address and related network configuration on the clone.)

Keep in mind that there are no external clients authenticating against the AD instance, and no other domain members (workstations or servers).

Comment: I can't think of any reason this would be a problem. It's a standalone AD instance unto itself. I've done this with SBS before to give salespeople their own copy of a demo environment for a software package that integrated with Exchange Server and SQL Server.

Comment: If the two domain controllers can't pass traffic to each other, how would there be a problem?  Of course, domain controllers really don't like having their IPs changed, but I assume you've considered that already.

Comment: @HopelessN00b They can pass traffic to each other just fine if they're on the same subnet.  The question is, does that matter?

Comment: Why do you need AD in a self-contained environment vs. using local accounts?

Comment: @TheCleaner application requirement (AD integration is an important feature)

Comment: @jlehtinen Well, I had assumed that if you're putting it on the same subnet, you'd exercise an abundance of caution and block communication between the two servers, but as far as I can figure, there should be no effect if the two do communicate - as a standalone setup, the DC wouldn't be set to replicate with any other DC, so it should be safe.  That said, it's certainly something I'd test first (clone two copies onto a different subnet, and see if they cause each other to implode), because that sounds like something that would be especially unpleasant to experience.

Comment: If it is "self contained" why does it need ANY network connectivity? Give the VM no VLAN, no network connectivity. Use the VM console app to connect to the VM instead of RDP.

Comment: @Craig620 Appreciate the input, but I'm not looking for workarounds - I'm genuinely interested in knowing if there is any real issue with doing this.

Comment: Two DC's for the same domain on the same subnet, no problem. But cloning one DC and running a copy of it on the same subnet with a different IP? That will never work. They see each other, try to replicate, kablooey!